# Get the process ID in a Shell script when a process is launched in foreground

Tags: linux, shell

In a shell program I want to launch a program and get its PID and save in a temp file. But here I will launch the program in the foreground and will not exit the shell until the process is in running state

ex:

```
 #!/bin/bash

 myprogram &
 echo "$!"  > /tmp/pid
```

And this works fine i am able to get the pid of the launched process . But if i launch the program in fore ground i want to know how to get the pid

ex :

```
#!/bin/bash

myprogram       /// hear some how i wan to know the PID before going to next line
```

Comment: If your program is running in foreground then how will you even go to next line?

Comment: or is it possible to launch the program in background and get the process ID and then wait the script till that process gets exited ?

Comment: Yes that can be done, see my edited answer below.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As I commented above since your command is still running in foreground you cannot enter a new command in the same shell and goto the next line.

However while this command is running and you want to get the process id of this program from a different shell tab/window process then use `pgrep` like this:

```
pgrep -f "myprogram"
17113 # this # will be different for you :P
```

**EDIT:** Base on your comment `or is it possible to launch the program in background and get the process ID and then wait the script till that process gets exited ?`

Yes that can be done using `wait pid` command as follows:

```
myprogram &
mypid=$!
# do some other stuff and then
wait $mypid
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this since your shell script isn't running -- the command you just launched in the foreground is.